# ¿Cómo puedo cargar solo el contenido filtrado por busqueda en una tabla json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tengo en una web una tabla enorme en json que hace que se relentize la carga de la página. Quisiera saber, si con la barra de búsqueda que tengo puedo hacer que solo se carguen los resultados del filtro de búsqueda y todo lo demás quede sin cargar para tener una mejor respuesta de carga.

Aquí tengo el HTML con la barra de búsqueda y la tabla que se genera por otra parte con los datos del json

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Escriba la monodroga o el nombre comercial">

                    <table id="myTable" class="table table-responsive table-striped tab-vademecum">
                        <tbody class="cuerpo-tabla resultados-vademecum"></tbody>
                    </table>
```

Aquí está el código que use para cargar y filtrar el contenido del JSON.

```
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, j, visible;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    visible = false;
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
      if (td[j] && td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        visible = true;
      }
    }
    if (visible === true) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(".resultados-vademecum").append("<tr><td colspan='5'>Cargando lista...</td></tr>");
  setTimeout(function() {CargarVademecum();}, 2000) 
});


function CargarVademecum() {
  $(".resultados-vademecum").html("");
  $.getJSON('js/vademecum.json', function (data) {
    aux = "";
    contentHTML = "";
     $.each(data, function (key, val) {
      if (aux !== val.Monodroga) {
        aux =  val.Monodroga;
        contentHTML += "<tr><td colspan='5' class='tt-tabla'>" + aux + "</td></tr>";
      }

      contentHTML += 
        "<tr>" +
        "<td class='troquel'>" + val.Troquel + "</td>" +
        "<td class='monodroga'>" + val.Monodroga + "</td>" +
        "<td class='nombre'>" + val.Nombre + "</td>" +
        "<td class='potencia'>" + val.Potencia + "</td>" +
        "<td class='cobertura'>" + val.Cobertura + "</td>" +
        "</tr>";
    });

    $(".resultados-vademecum").html(contentHTML);
  });

}
```

Quisiera saber cómo podría hacer que solo cargue la búsqueda realizada y todos los demás elementos de la tabla queden ocultos siempre.

Espero que puedan ayudarme, no tengo mucha idea de todo esto y no se ya muy bien cómo llegué hasta programar esto. 
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Al querer ocultar los registros, internamente los estan llamando igual y no optimizara nada. Lo que podrías hacer es mostrar filtros y al realizar la busqueda ir a la API y obtener los resultados que desean.

Comment: Como dice @PauloUrbanoRivera, al final no consigues nada, ya que necesitas poder aplicar una logia a esos datos antes de devolverlos, y teniéndolos en un archivo json no creo que sea posible. Lo mejor opción es hacer una petición a una API pasandole los filtros.

Comment: Como dicen los demás comentarios deberías hacer la consulta a un API aplicando los filtros ahí, pasa los datos de tu archivo json a una DB y trabaja estos datos desde tu backend, esto asegura la escalabilidad de tu informacion y su sustentabilidad.